# R plotly - How to make labels and legend larger in donut chart?

Tags: r, plotly

I'm making a donut chart with the following code

```
data <- data.frame(
  category=c("Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Pending"),
  amount=c(45, 26, 23)
)

# Make the plot
df <- data
fig <- df %>% plot_ly(labels = ~category, values = ~amount, marker = list(colors = c('#00aa7f', '#ff0000','#ccccc7')))
fig <- fig %>% add_pie(hole = 0.55) 
fig
```

This results in a nice donut chart - but I feel like the legend and label are too small.
[image]

```
When I edit my code with the following: Nothing happens

df <- data
fig <- df %>% plot_ly(labels = ~category, values = ~amount, marker = list(colors = c('#00aa7f', '#ff0000','#ccccc7', size = 10)))
fig <- fig %>% add_pie(hole = 0.55) 
fig
```

When I try this code - the font is way to big and although I try to adjust it - the size doesn't decrease.

```
# Make the plot
df <- data
fig <- df %>% plot_ly(labels = ~category, values = ~amount, marker = list(colors = c('#00aa7f', '#ff0000','#ccccc7')), size = 10)
fig <- fig %>% add_pie(hole = 0.55) 
fig
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The label size can the changed by `textfont` argument inside the `add_pie` function. The legend size and hovertext size can be adjusted inside the `layout` function with the arguments `hoverlabel` and `legend`.

```
fig <- df %>% plot_ly(labels = ~category,
                      values = ~amount, 
                      marker = list(colors = c('#00aa7f', '#ff0000','#ccccc7')))
fig <- fig %>% 
  add_pie(hole = 0.55,
          textfont = list(size = 18))  %>%
  layout(legend = list(font = list(size = 18)),
         hoverlabel = list(font = list(size = 18)))
fig
```

[image]